# JTable Cell Isn't Updated On Enter Click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have an app that has a JTable of some data.. So I add the data and it appears well.. But when I try to edit a cell, I can edit it but when I click enter or tab to save the new content it reflects as it was earlier.. I don't know why that happens.. I searched online but with no hope.. :(

Here is the Table Model class :

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

String[] columnNames = { "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6" };

private List<Entry> db;
JTable table;

public TableModel(JTable table) {
    this.table = table;
}

public void addRow(Entry entry) {
    db.add(entry);
    fireTableRowsInserted(db.size() - 1, db.size() - 1);
    table.editCellAt(db.size() -1, 0);
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return true;
}

public void setData(List<Entry> db) {
    this.db = db;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 6;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return db.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Entry entry = db.get(row);

    try {
        switch (col) {
        case 0:
            return entry.getItem();
        case 1:
            return entry.getTransPayment();
        case 2:
            return entry.getEquipPayment();
        case 3:
            return entry.getGasPayment();
        case 4:
            return entry.getEquipSparePayment();
        case 5:
            return entry.getTransSparePayment();
        case 6:
            return entry.getTotal();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }


    return null;
}


}
```

The question is : Do I need to add any custom methods or code to do what I mentioned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when I click enter or tab to save the new content it reflects as it was earlier..

Your `TableModel` doesn't implement the `setValueAt(...)` method so the data from the editor is never saved.

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
{
    Entry entry = db.get(row);

    switch (column)
    {
        case 0: entry.setItem(value); break;
        case 1: entry.setTransPayment(value); break;
        ...
    }

    fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping you could do this with a custom `TableCellEditor`, but that didn't turn out to be the case.

You need to provide a key binding for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, which would allow you to associate an appropriate action for the key, for example...

```
public class EditSelectedCellAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JTable table;

    public EditSelectedCellAction(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();

        if (col >= 0 && row >= 0) {
            table.editCellAt(row, col);
        }
    }

}
```

You would then need to bind the `EditSelectedCellAction` to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, for example...

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();

KeyStroke enterKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
im.put(enterKey, "Action.enter");
am.put("Action.enter", new EditSelectedCellAction(table));
```

*Feedback*

There is never any reason why a model should ever have a reference to any view component, ever.  The model should simply not care.  A model could be associated with multiple views (in this case, tables), making in practical to maintain a reference to any view component.

Instead, what ever is calling your `addRow` method should be making the decisions to edit the cell.  Maybe, your `addRow` method could return the row index.

Also, in you `getValueAt` method, you call `fireTableDataChanged();` if, for some reason, something goes wrong, this could set up a nasty chain reaction which could place your program in an infinite loop and is best avoided

**Updated**

You know, at first, I though you hadn't overriden `isCellEditable`, but as it turns out, you've not override `setValueAt`

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    Entry entry = db.get(rowIndex);
    switch (colIndex) {
        case 0:
            entry.getItem();
            break;
        case 1:
            entry.setTransPayment(aValue);
            break;
        case 2:
            entry.setEquipPayment(aValue);
            break;
        case 3:
            entry.setGasPayment(aValue);
            break;
        case 4:
            entry.setEquipSparePayment(aValue);
            break;
        case 5:
            entry.setTransSparePayment(aValue);
            break;
        case 6:
            entry.setTotal(aValue);
            break;
    }
    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, colIndex);
}
```

Now, because you didn't provide the source for `Entry`, I need to guess at its data types and functionality

Comment: Thanks for explanation but this code only select the cell to edit when it's focused.. And when I click enter after I edit no thing happens.. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you explain "click enter"?

Comment: What I mean is: I click on the cell to edit it.. Now I can edit it.. I type what I need and now I wanna save the new data.. I wanna click the enter key to do this, but now that has no effect